# What does "he=e-1" mean in vim syntax file?

Tags: vim, syntax

I am studying asm68k.vim and find `he=e-1` after some syntax definitions. As I read I guess it makes the matched word one character shorter than what the pattern actually matches but I am not sure. Take the following definition for example I think it skips the `:` at the end of what the pattern matches,

```
syn match asm68kLabel           "^\s*[a-z_?.][a-z0-9_?.$]*:"he=e-1
```

Could anyone help to explain what does it mean and where to find the manual which explains `he` and `e`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This defines a character offset for the specified match pattern. You can learn about pattern offsets here:

```
:help syn-pattern-offset
```

In your case, `he=e-1` offsets the end of the highlighting by -1 characters from the end of the match. There are several similar syntax items for offsetting the start and end of the match or region.